# Where should I be when working in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I've just installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper on my computer. Now I want to use it to work with Django. When I run `mkvirtualenv django`, from `~`, the interpreter stays there. Does that mean I can create my django files there? Or is the environment not **that** virtual? Should I create my own folder instead where I work on the project? I thought `mkvirtualenv` would create one for me automatically and take me there upon running `workon`, otherwise, what's the point of even using virtualenvwrapper?

EDIT: These few lines from my .bash_profile might help you:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

virtualenwrapper will create the virtualenv in your ~$WORKON_HOME/ directory. This is the venv only and is distinct from any associated "project" directory you might (or not...) want to use and which virtualenvwrapper will indeed not create.

IOW, at this point you are exactly in the same directory as when you ran the `mkvirtualenv` command.

If you want to associate this venv to a project directory, you have to create this directory (if it does not exist yet), and then - with your venv activated - run `setvirtualenvproject /path/to/your/projectdir` (or `cd /path/to/your/projectdir` and here run `setvirtualenvproject` without argument).

Once done with this, next time you activate your venv with `workon myenv`, you will be automagically cd'ed to your project directory too, and the `cdproject` command will bring you back there if you cd elsewhere.

As for other reasons to use (or not) virtualenwrapper, you can read the doc and find out by yourself what other features it adds to the raw `virtualenv` and whether you want those features or not.

FWIW the behaviour you expected (creating both the venv AND the project dir) is given by [the `mkproject` command](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#mkproject)

Comment: What does "IOW" mean?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE In Other Words (autrement dit)

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of virtualenvwrapper is the separation of your environment from a specific working directory. Just activate your environment with:

```
workon django
```

The prompt should change to:

```
(django)
```

Now you are free to work from any directory you want.